# How to assign Promise to JSON before await kicks

Tags: node.js

I have a small problem.

I have a command that executes in 2 ways.

```
runningTests // global array I want to push status to
```

A) Normal
Executes code only once

```
jStatusFormat.status=fnRunOnce(); // fnRunOnce returns promise 
runningTests.push(jStatusFormat);
```

so After this one I have inside runingTests=[{status:pending}]

B) Group
Executes code in for loop as many times as is Needed. On fnRunOnce response the loop continues with another iteration.

```
async loop(){ // just loop that is made to iterate after response
   jStatusFormat.status=await fnRunOnce(); // fnRunOnce returns promise 
    runningTests.push(jStatusFormat);
}
```

so After this one I have nothing inside runingTests=[] and I have to wait for await to kicks in order to get my object into array.

## Problem

How can I push t my array before awaits kick but with defined status ?

## possible Solution

I can push to an array before I call the function but I need To somehow assign new promise to it.

If something is unclear just write please I ll respond

Comment: So in the group case you want to have a Promise assigned to jStatusFormat.status that is the final call from the last iteration of the loop?

Comment: "something is unclear just write please I ll respond" has time to edit question twice but doesn't respond to comment asking for clarification. Hilarious.

Comment: I have no seen it when I was editing sorry.

Comment: Well In each iteration I need to push to runningTests and I would like to see promise pending. IF I do it before fnRunOnce then status ll be null, after is too late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const promiseArray = []
async loop(){ // just loop that is made to iterate after response
   promiseArray.push(fnRunOnce())
}

jStatusFormat.status = Promise.all(promiseArray)
runningTests.push(jStatusFormat);
```

Comment: This does not work as I need to be able to see each promise in array  before fnRunOnce() is finished

Comment: each promise in array can be seen in `promiseArray`

Comment: Yes But you ll see it in runningTests just after the loop is done. Which is in my case useless, but Good idea anyway Thx

Comment: I fixed it similar way you did. Instead Of promise I attached just value string status. Then I updated after it was done

Answer (score -1):

You should remove `await` . I am not sure that there is another option in your case.

Comment: its not cause it holds async loop waiting for response. If i remove it my asnyc loop ll wont loop in sequence